# Why I get rectangle wrapped icon on the button?

Tags: html, css

I create css class with background-image property.

Here is css class:

```
.showLayers{
    background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-online-2/64/layers_server_online_web_internet-128.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

And here is two other css classes that I use:

```
.miniToolbarContant{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.button_air-medium {
  cursor: pointer;
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 36px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="button_air-medium ">
        <img id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant showLayers"/>
</button>
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

And here is [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/e11ja7L3/2/).

As you can see on the image above I have rectangle that wrap the icon.

My question is how to remove rectangle that wrap the icon?

Comment: that border might be part of the image (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the image as a background-image for an `img` tag, which doesn't make sense. Use a `div` tag instead: https://jsfiddle.net/kbz6opss/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `<img>` tag, try to not use `<img>` when background images is used.

Answer (score 0):

css is weird, if you use img tag you want to use the src attribute

```html
<img id="showLayers"src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-online-2/64/layers_server_online_web_internet-128.png" class="miniToolbarContant showLayers"/>
```

and remove background url from css,
else it will create that border no matter what you do (as far as I know of).

Comment: i need to  change the  background-img of img element when button is clicked.

Comment: why not do it in javascript

Comment: I use jquery for this purpose.I have two css classes with two different background-image property